# Documentation for troyworks flash framework

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4

I want to  design a Flash CS4(AS3) based kiosk application where the screen changes according to the multi-user events.
Due to the fact that Troywork's supports HFSM, it might be useful to my needs, but its hardly documented. I checked the dir structure, but cannot understand the usage. Is there any documentation to get started using the framework? Can someone suggest some examples?

reference : http://code.google.com/p/troyworks

Directory file structure:

```
+---apps
|   +---.settings
|   +---build
|   +---docs
|   \---src
|       \---com
|           \---troyworks
|               \---apps
|                   +---mnemosyne
|                   +---semantica
|                   |   \---moby
|                   +---templateengine
|                   +---tester
|                   \---tgesture
+---controls
|   +---.settings
|   \---src
|       \---com
|           \---troyworks
|               \---controls
|                   +---cogsDebugger
|                   +---menu
|                   +---tarrow
|                   +---tautocomplete
|                   |   \---ui
|                   +---tbutton
|                   +---tcalc
|                   +---tcalendar
|                   +---tcarouselmenus
|                   +---tcookie
|                   +---tcursor
|                   +---tdatefield
|                   +---tdraggable
|                   +---tflow
|                   +---tform
|                   +---tkoosh
|                   +---tline
|                   +---tloadingIndicator
|                   +---tmediaplayer
|                   |   +---controller
|                   |   +---model
|                   |   \---ui
|                   +---tmodal
|                   +---tparticleengine
|                   |   \---forces
|                   +---tqa
|                   +---tscrollbar
|                   +---tshapes
|                   +---tsliderbar
|                   +---tslidermenu
|                   +---ttextfield
|                   +---ttooltip
|                   +---ttree
|                   |   +---dataproviders
|                   |   +---managers
|                   |   +---tree
|                   |   \---treeclasses
|                   +---tuitools
|                   \---tuseridle
+---dev
|   +---build
|   +---docs
|   \---src
|       +---com
|       |   +---adobe
|       |   |   +---crypto
|       |   |   +---errors
|       |   |   +---images
|       |   |   +---net
|       |   |   |   \---proxies
|       |   |   +---serialization
|       |   |   |   \---json
|       |   |   +---utils
|       |   |   \---webapis
|       |   |       \---events
|       |   \---troyworks
|       |       +---core
|       |       |   +---chain
|       |       |   +---cogs
|       |       |   |   \---proxies
|       |       |   +---commands
|       |       |   +---events
|       |       |   +---patterns
|       |       |   +---persistance
|       |       |   |   +---foundation
|       |       |   |   +---implementation
|       |       |   |   +---syncher
|       |       |   |   \---wrapper
|       |       |   +---score
|       |       |   +---time
|       |       |   \---tweeny
|       |       |       \---fx
|       |       +---data
|       |       |   +---bit
|       |       |   +---btree
|       |       |   +---constraints
|       |       |   +---enums
|       |       |   +---filters
|       |       |   +---graph
|       |       |   +---id
|       |       |   +---iterators
|       |       |   +---query
|       |       |   +---skiplist
|       |       |   |   +---simple
|       |       |   |   \---visitable
|       |       |   +---tags
|       |       |   +---validators
|       |       |   \---valueobjects
|       |       +---events
|       |       +---framework
|       |       |   +---assets
|       |       |   +---controller
|       |       |   +---framework
|       |       |   +---internationalization
|       |       |   +---loader
|       |       |   +---model
|       |       |   +---security
|       |       |   +---tiers
|       |       |   +---ui
|       |       |   |   \---layout
|       |       |   \---user
|       |       +---geom
|       |       |   +---d1
|       |       |   +---d2
|       |       |   \---d3
|       |       +---io
|       |       |   +---airlib
|       |       |   \---fplib
|       |       +---logging
|       |       +---reflection
|       |       +---snippets
|       |       |   +---patterns
|       |       |   \---reflection
|       |       +---text
|       |       +---ui
|       |       |   \---sketch
|       |       \---util
|       |           +---codeGen
|       |           |   \---model
|       |           +---datetime
|       |           \---swfconnect
|       \---util
+---docs
|   \---checkingout
+---examples
|   +---bin
|   +---doc
|   +---SaveImage
|   |   \---PostReceiver
|   |       \---data
|   +---src
|   |   +---Calc
|   |   |   +---dev
|   |   |   |   +---build
|   |   |   |   |   \---lib
|   |   |   |   \---src
|   |   |   \---spec
|   |   +---classes
|   |   |   \---com
|   |   |       \---troyworks
|   |   |           +---commandexample
|   |   |           |   +---commandcontainers
|   |   |           |   +---commands
|   |   |           |   +---controls
|   |   |           |   \---shapes
|   |   |           +---dayinlife
|   |   |           +---prevayler
|   |   |           |   \---demo1
|   |   |           \---Tdining_philosophers
|   |   +---Cogs
|   |   |   +---dev
|   |   |   +---docs
|   |   |   \---src
|   |   +---CommandExample
|   |   |   \---obj
|   |   +---Controls
|   |   |   \---MixinPlayer
|   |   +---DiningPhilosophers
|   |   +---LayoutUtil
|   |   |   +---build
|   |   |   |   \---slugs
|   |   |   \---src
|   |   +---Prevayler
|   |   |   \---obj
|   |   +---QA
|   |   +---Sketch
|   |   |   +---addFrameScript
|   |   |   +---Clickthrough
|   |   |   +---ColorUtil
|   |   |   +---doc
|   |   |   |   \---src
|   |   |   +---EngineLoader
|   |   |   +---FlowControl
|   |   |   |   +---embedded
|   |   |   |   \---external
|   |   |   +---FrameEvents
|   |   |   +---LateBindingView
|   |   |   |   \---bin
|   |   |   +---SymbolClass
|   |   |   \---Tweens and saving state
|   |   +---StopWatch
|   |   \---Validation
|   +---StMPE
|   |   \---dev
|   |       +---build
|   |       \---src
|   |           +---mdl
|   |           \---ui
|   \---tgesture
\---tests
    +---bin
    +---obj
    |   \---basic
    \---src
        \---com
            \---troyworks
                +---apps
                |   \---tester
                +---core
                |   +---chain
                |   +---cogs
                |   \---patterns
                +---data
                +---framework
                |   \---loader
                +---geom
                |   \---d1
                +---logging
                +---prevayler
                +---tester
                +---text
                \---util
                    \---datetime
```